# Remove certain variables from all URLs in html

Tags: php

I'm really not sure if this is possible, but I want to be able to remove certain variable from all links in html content. e.g. I want to remove 'var1=1234' from every URL in the html document where that variable is present.

This works to remove all URLs, but I only really want to remove certain variables.

```
echo preg_replace('#<a.*?>([^>]*)</a>#i', '$1', $string);
```

Comment: Do you want to replace all links with var1=… or only the parameter. Either way you need to adjust the Regex. Do you also have var1, var2…?

Comment: @Villanelle - wherever var1 is present I want to replace the value. e.g. url.com/dashboard?var1=1234 change to url.com/dashboard?var1=4321. There is additional variables in the URLs - I want these to stay the same. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Do you wish to do the replacements at "runtime" or do you intend to process all pages once and fix hardcoded links in one operation? How are these urls generated - are they statically typed into your HTML/PHP pages?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best approach but working:

```
$string = preg_replace('/(var1=)(.*?)([&|\"])/','${1}4321${3}',$string);
```

Short explanation: The Regex matches 3 groups. First group is var1=, second group the value itself and third group is either a & or " (& for the next parameter like &var2=... and " for the ending of the link href="...").
The replacement is the first group + new value + third group.

I hope this works for you.